# Multiple Insert at once then updating vs Inserting with values by event performance

Tags: mysql, database

Before asking the question, I would like to provide you with some details.
I'm working on reporting web application which has let's say around 100 users, on daily basis a report is uploaded to the server and all the users are required to respond to it, and of course I keep track using mySQL DB. 
From performance and efficiency stand point, which is better:

- On each upload instance, create empty rows for each user and then when they respond update the row's values. Or
- Don't create anything once uploading is done, but when a user reply create the row and insert its values.

The application is going to scale really fast, and I would like to know which method to go with or even if you have something different on your mind please don't hesitate suggesting.
Thank you for the great efforts you are putting in this great community :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just do inserts.

The traditional way would be to have two tables:

```
REPORT_USER
   userid

REPORT_USER_ACCESS
   reportid
   userid
   access_time
```

You would only insert into REPORT_USER_ACCESS when a user looks at the table.  To get the list of users and if they accessed the report use an outer join:

select
  ru.userid,
  ra.reportid,
  ra.access_time
from 
  REPORT_USER ru
    left outer joing REPORT_USER_ACCESS ra on ru.userid = ra.userid
where
  ra.reportid =

The access_time will be null for users that have not accessed the report.  If you truly scale and have millions of users and you run this all the time you might find that the outer join is too expensive.